# Set GCP Developer Portal Public

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Edit: According a [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52263247/7933478) in September 2018 by an Endpoints team member, it is not yet possible.

I've just finished both GCP's [Endpoints OpenAPI Cloud Functions getting started](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions), and [Developer Portal](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/dev-portal-create) tutorials. Right now, [my project's developer portal](https://endpointsportal.gce-gcf-openapi-tutorial.cloud.goog/) requires the user sign into their Google account and possess the correct permissions to view it.

How can I open my GCP project's developer portal to be available to anyone who visits it?

Answer (score 1):

At this point you have to create either a user account or a service account to enable access to the developer portal. The user then needs to enter their credentials to gain access.

Please refer to [1] for more details.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/access-control#developers